# how to change a obj value in the uploader (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, uploader

i still try to change just 1 value on thish Script via js (remotePath), please give me informations :)

Thank you!

```
$('#uploader_div').ajaxupload(
        {
        url:            'upload.php',
        dropArea:       '#drop_here',
        remotePath:     'user/user1/',  <-- how to change only this value
        ...
```

like this

```
            remotePath:     'user/user2/'
```

Update:

```
<div id="uploader_div"></div>
<a id="link" href="#" onclick="newvalue();"> Change user2 </a> <!--Change by Click-->
<script>
    var uplobj = {
        url: 'upload.php',
        dropArea: '#drop_here',
        remotePath: 'user/user1/', // Change by Click
        autoStart: true,
        hideUploadButton: true,
        removeOnSuccess: true, 
        maxConnections: 0,
        maxFileSize: '20M',
        allowExt: ['mp3']
    };
    function newvalue() 
    {
        uplobj.remotePath = 'user/user2/'; // Change by Click
        link.style.display = 'none';
    };    
    $('#uploader_div').ajaxupload(uplobj);
</script>
```

Comment: When are you trying to change this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change an object anytime before the ajax call if you have a reference to it.

```
var obj = {
    url:            'upload.php',
    dropArea:       '#drop_here',
    remotePath:     'user/user1/'
};
obj.remotePath = 'user/user2/';
$('#uploader_div').ajaxupload(obj);
```

**EDIT in response to more code**

I read through the [docs](https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Ajax-Upload) you are supposed to pass a standard jquery options object to ajaxupload. Right now you have a mix of jquery options and the data perhaps see the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info on what settings are valid.

A simple fix might be putting your current data in the data options attribute.

```
$('#uploader_div').ajaxupload({data: obj});
```

Comment: thank you its works but not in js function :(

function newvalue() 
{           uplobj.remotePath= 'user/user2/';
}

Comment: You need a reference to the object that you are passing to ajaxupload. I will need to see more of your code to be able to help you figure out whats wrong exactly.

Comment: thank you but it does not .woeks so that no data will be loaded